# PHP - If statement not working correctly in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, foreach

Hi I have this code here:

```
public function length($args) {
    if (isset($this->length)) {
        foreach ($this->length as $k => $v) {
            if (strlen($args[$k])>=$v[0] && strlen($args[$k])<$v[1]) {
                return true;
            } else {
                array_push($this->form_errors, $v[2]);
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else { 
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why but its not working as expected. The foreach loop only loops through one of the $args[$k] even though there are 2 of them. Anyone have any idea whats going on? I'm writing this question in a hurry so if I need to explain anything else, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us print_r($this->length)

Comment: put return value into variable and return it at the end of function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your two `return` statements in both sides of the `if()` clause terminate the function on the first iteration of the loop. Either the strlen stuff is true and you return true, or they're false and you return false. regardless, the loop ends.

If you simply want to jump to the next iteration, then use `continue` instead, which'd allow the foreach to proceed.

Comment: But there's no need for a `continue`, because there's nothing else in the loop.